# Someone help me in this error TypeError at /contact 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-request

Views.py

```
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def project(request):
    return render(request, 'project.html')

def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
     name=request.POST.get['name']
    email=request.POST.get['email']
    phone=request.POST.get['phone']
    concern=request.POST.get['concern']
    print(name,email,phone,'concern') 
    obj=Contact(name='name', email='email',phone='phone',concern='concern')
    obj.save()

    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

I am trying to connect my contact form with database but after post method it doesn't allow me.

Comment: `name=request.POST.get['name']` Use parentheses `()`, not square brackets `[]`.  Parentheses are correct syntax for calling a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `get()` not `get[]` and also it's a good practice to return HttpResponseRedirect after dealing with POST data, the tip is not specific to Django, it's a good web practice in general, so the view should be:

```py
def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
       name=request.POST.get('name')
       email=request.POST.get('email')
       phone=request.POST.get('phone')
       concern=request.POST.get('concern')
       print(name,email,phone,concern) 
       obj=Contact(name=name, email=email,phone=phone,concern=concern)
       obj.save()
       return redirect('some_path_name')

    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```